# How to login to a server as a mysql user in order to stop the mysql server?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a linux server instance hosted by RunAbove where I log in as an 'admin' user using an ssh key.

I need to change the mysql root password on the server manually. I'm following directions given [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

The problem I have is that I log in to the server as an 'admin' user while the 'mysqld' process is owned by 'mysql' user (this process below):

```
Feb21  54:48 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I need to send `kill` signal to `mysqld.pid`, but I'm not able to do it even if I execute it with `sudo` as an 'admin' user.

RunAbove allows me to ssh into the only server as 'admin'.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have the password of root of mysql or any user with full controll of mysql, you can use mysqladmin in this way:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

You can login as root in your server and use the script of your distribution to stop mysql